# CSS: Text beneath image does not break to new line

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute positioned div. Inside this div there is an image and underneath it, a caption. Now I want the caption to break to new a line if it reaches 95% width of the image.

But I can't get it to work. The text (no matter what width I say), always moves the image to the left like it would have no breaks.

I made a fiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hw7t7xyn/1/

The image is set to

```
right: 0;
top: 10px;
```

But since the text is too long it moves to the left.

Also the `div.caption` does not seem to adopt the parents div width.

Can anybody help me out here? Maybe it's a problem of the HTML setup or the CSS, I have no idea anymore, but it's driving me crazy.

**Update:** Sorry, I did forget to mention that I don't know the dimensions of the image. Is there a possible way to do this without javascript?

Comment: You're trying to make the text 95% of the image width, but are setting it to 95% of the div width...Why not specify the width of the caption in px (i.e. 0.95*260 = 247px)?

Comment: See update in question

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add a width to the main div (the one that's absolute positioned).

I added a width of 260px (same as the image)

When I did this, it aligned the div to the far right as you have `right:0px` is this correct?

http://jsfiddle.net/hw7t7xyn/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
div.photo-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width:260px;
}

img.photo {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

div.caption {
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 95%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-bock;
}
```

give width to photo-wrap